# Parsing Math Expression in android

Tags: java, android

About my Project:
I want to solve math expression which i have in a String, i tried using `javax.script.ScriptEngineManager` but its not working, i guess it does not work in android.
so i am trying to write a code for parsing math expression, for this I'm using following code:

```
str = "2.2+3.3*6.6";
ArrayList<String> bufffer = new ArrayList<String>();
String temp = "";
for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(j)) || str.charAt(j) == '.') {
        char c = str.charAt(j);
        temp = temp + String.valueOf(c);
    }
    if (str.charAt(j) == '+' || str.charAt(j) == '-' || str.charAt(j) == '*' || str.charAt(j) == '/') {
        bufffer.add(temp);
        temp = "";
        bufffer.add(String.valueOf(str.charAt(j)));
    } 
}
bufffer.add(temp);
```

Once I separated values from operators, I perform basic math operations finding multiply and divide operators first. So I'm getting perfect output for simple expression like `2.2+3.3*6.6 = 23.97999`. I believe I can write code for expression `2*(3+6*9)` by finding first and last parentheses and call same method `3+6*9` string.

**Here is my problem**: what if my expression be like `(3+2)*(6+3)` or `3+((2+3)*(6+5))`? Basically I want a code that can find parentheses index which should be solved first.

Once I solve this, I will write code for parsing sin, cos, log etc, but they are future problems.

Comment: Using ScriptEngineManager is definitely a better way to solve this problem than trying to re-invent everything by yourself. Do you have any stacktrace linked to the error you've had using it ?

Comment: I can't read that at all--have you considered indentation? In general, expression parsing will want a stack. That said, this problem has been solved a million times over, and a rudimentary search will provide tons of examples.

Comment: Throw it all away and use an existing solution. You won't get there by guesswork like this. Use the script engine, or look up recursive descent expression parsing, or the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm.

Comment: ok I'm using BeanShell now. it was also not working first like javax.script.ScriptEngineManager.... problem was that it wasn't synchronizing with project. so i edited build file and wrote compile code for my external jars file. now its working properly.